# Issuing authenticated queries with Graphcool

Tags: authentication, graphql, auth0, relayjs, graphcool

I have successfully set up [Graph.cool](https://graph.cool/) Auth0 authentication and created a User through Relay as described [here](https://github.com/graphcool-examples/auth0-lock-example/issues/3).

Next I'd like to actually query graph.cool on behalf of this user. As a first step, I simply manually modified the Relay setup to specify the same auth token as was used to create the User in the first place (through the `idToken` on type `AUTH_PROVIDER_AUTH0`):

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer(process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer XXX.YYY.ZZZ',
    },
  })
);
```

However, the app stops rendering and I just get a console warning `RelayPendingQueryTracker.js:153 Server response was missing for query Index`. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling the signinUser or createUser mutation, a Graphcool token is returned in the payload. https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/graphcool-session-user-goij0cooqu

This is the token you need to use in the Authorization header instead of the Auth0 idToken.

Maybe it can also be a help to take a look at how we do it in the dashboard https://github.com/graphcool/dashboard/blob/master/src/views/LoginView/LoginView.tsx

Hope this helps!